# How to avoid resource locking/file overwrite for generated email attachment?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, locking, submission

Pretty standard request. I have a form where a visitor enters contact information to report interest in a product. But the budget does not allow database storage, login, human-readable formatting. Instead, the form data is emailed to them with a PDF that I generate.

The submit button makes an AJAX call which on callback generates an image file for the PDF and the PDF.

Is there a way to number the generated files or otherwise avoid file overwrites or locks, if two visitors submit their form at the same time?

The email is sent with Wordpress' wp_mail(). Is it safe to delete the file immediately after return from this function?

Comment: I would say use the combination of timestamp and anything unique in the contact information that the user fills in the form as the file name and that will be unique and hence no conflicts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a unique file name you can use a guid instead of a timestamp.

```
$filename = com_create_guid() . '.pdf';
```

or if you dont have php >=5

```
$data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$filename = '.pdf'; 
for ($x = 0; $x < 16; $x++)
   $filename = bin2hex($data[x]) . $filename;
```

Comment: I will try a GUID, and use it for the image for the PDF and the PDF and then delete the files when the email has been sent. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work. Using com_create_guid() on PHP 7.0.20 causes an execution error, don't know which one because it's inside the AJAX callback. Some missing require? Causing invalid filename/string as appended? Dunno. Using milliseconds works with no other change.